How to make zero padding gradually smoother for continous data?
I have this continous data (amplitude):

I want to make gradually smoother for zero padding, actually I succeded using convolution. But it requires hard tuning and I'm not sure it's applied for all samples:

Here is my parameter of convolution am I using:
start_onset = padded_beat_rolled[:int(360 * 0.1)]
start_onset_convolved = np.convolve(start_onset, np.ones(25)*0.06, 'same')

plt.plot(start_onset)
plt.plot(start_onset_convolved)
plt.show()

As you see I have no reason why the num of kernel is setted up like that because I tuned it manually, I expect I can generalize this for all samples.

